# Why are upvotes to a question not calculated on the user page's tags tab?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

Why don't upvotes to questions show in the scores in the appropriate tag [on the user page, the tags tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130809/abatishchev?tab=tags)? Only upvotes to answer do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstood something; tags on *any* SE site only show the vote count for answers.

If you mouse-over the number you'll also get the question up-vote count, but for tag badge purposes only answer votes count.

For example, here's my (measly) SuperUser tag count for one tag; note that I have 4 upvotes for my question with the `osx` tag but only one upvote for my answers:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explanation! I don't like this though.

Comment: I still don't understand why does it happen. Why on Q&A site only A are counted, not Q too. Especially on Meta.

Comment: Qs do count, but in reputation only. Tag badges are only awarded for answers; no point in having questions if noone answers them!

Comment: Answering good questions is important thing too, don't you agree, also good questions (popular, highly voted) are awarded too as answer are.